# Remove Default JavaScripts in Wicket 7 Application

Tags: javascript, java, html, wicket

Is there a way to remove all .js so I can add manually in a Wicket 7 Application?

The code next doesn't work nicelly:

```
@Override 
protected void init() {
    getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().setJQueryReference(new UrlResourceReference(Url.parse("")));
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior after doing this ? I could try it but it is weekend :-)

Comment: It will complain that the String should not be empty, easily corrected by changing the String to " "...but it keeps the tag <script> and it would be nice to have a clean code without the tag <script>...

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use header contribution filtering. See 
this article http://wicketinaction.com/2012/07/wicket-6-resource-management/ and its demo app: 
https://github.com/martin-g/blogs/blob/c29f0875910d3bd5e11bca0d2c0fa8cdd84e3736/wicket6-resource-management/src/main/java/com/wicketinaction/ResourceManagementApplication.java#L102
The idea is to not call `super.render()` for the HeaderItems which you don't want to be contributed.

See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/0328021656bc68603c479502b2901f081bbb0588/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/head/filter/JavaScriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse.java for an example. It uses filters to decide where and what to render.